# Symfony error when trying to create a new project: Fatal error: Uncaught Symfony\Component\Dotenv\Exception\PathException: Unable to read .env

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

Whenever I try to create a new Symfony project using the following command:

```
composer create-project symfony/skeleton new_project
```

I'm getting these error messages in the console and I have no idea what causes it:

```
Executing script cache:clear [KO]
 [KO]
Script cache:clear returned with error code 255
!!
!!  Fatal error: Uncaught Symfony\Component\Dotenv\Exception\PathException: Unable to read the "C:\Users\ferra\Projects\PHPex\test_project/.env" environment file. in C:\Users\ferra\Projects\PHPex\test_project\vendor\symfony\dotenv\Dotenv.php:567
!!  Stack trace:
!!  #0 C:\Users\ferra\Projects\PHPex\test_project\vendor\symfony\dotenv\Dotenv.php(114): Symfony\Component\Dotenv\Dotenv->doLoad(false, Array)
!!  #1 C:\Users\ferra\Projects\PHPex\test_project\vendor\symfony\dotenv\Dotenv.php(157): Symfony\Component\Dotenv\Dotenv->loadEnv('C:\\Users\\ferra\\...', 'APP_ENV', 'dev', Array, false)
!!  #2 C:\Users\ferra\Projects\PHPex\test_project\vendor\symfony\runtime\SymfonyRuntime.php(107): Symfony\Component\Dotenv\Dotenv->bootEnv('C:\\Users\\ferra\\...', 'dev', Array, false)
!!  #3 C:\Users\ferra\Projects\PHPex\test_project\vendor\autoload_runtime.php(23): Symfony\Component\Runtime\SymfonyRuntime->__construct(Array)
!!  #4 C:\Users\ferra\Projects\PHPex\test_project\bin\console(11): require_once('C:\\Users\\ferra\\...')
!!  #5 {main}
!!    thrown in C:\Users\ferra\Projects\PHPex\test_project\vendor\symfony\dotenv\Dotenv.php on line 567
!!  PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Symfony\Component\Dotenv\Exception\PathException: Unable to read the "C:\Users\ferra\Projects\PHPex\test_project/.env" environment file. in C:\Users\ferra\Projects\PHPex\test_project\vendor\symfony\dotenv\Dotenv.php:567
!!  Stack trace:
!!  #0 C:\Users\ferra\Projects\PHPex\test_project\vendor\symfony\dotenv\Dotenv.php(114): Symfony\Component\Dotenv\Dotenv->doLoad(false, Array)
!!  #1 C:\Users\ferra\Projects\PHPex\test_project\vendor\symfony\dotenv\Dotenv.php(157): Symfony\Component\Dotenv\Dotenv->loadEnv('C:\\Users\\ferra\\...', 'APP_ENV', 'dev', Array, false)
!!  #2 C:\Users\ferra\Projects\PHPex\test_project\vendor\symfony\runtime\SymfonyRuntime.php(107): Symfony\Component\Dotenv\Dotenv->bootEnv('C:\\Users\\ferra\\...', 'dev', Array, false)
!!  #3 C:\Users\ferra\Projects\PHPex\test_project\vendor\autoload_runtime.php(23): Symfony\Component\Runtime\SymfonyRuntime->__construct(Array)
!!  #4 C:\Users\ferra\Projects\PHPex\test_project\bin\console(11): require_once('C:\\Users\\ferra\\...')
!!  #5 {main}
!!    thrown in C:\Users\ferra\Projects\PHPex\test_project\vendor\symfony\dotenv\Dotenv.php on line 567
!!
Script @auto-scripts was called via post-update-cmd
```

The following command: `'symfony check:requirements'` shows that my system is ready to run Symfony projects:

```
> PHP is using the following php.ini file:
C:\xampp\php\php.ini

> Checking Symfony requirements:

..............WWW......W..


 [OK]
 Your system is ready to run Symfony projects


Optional recommendations to improve your setup
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I'm not getting any errors when I try to create a demo project instead of a regular one (`symfony new --demo new_project`).

Does anyone know what's causing the error message when trying to create a new regular Symfony project?
Any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: This is the second time in the past couple of days that I’ve heard Windows users having problems like this, I’ll see if I can repro on my machine. In the meantime, can you just manually create the `.env` file?

Comment: Thanks, I've created the .env file manually and I can run the app fine now.

Answer (score 3):

The only solution at the moment is to create the file **.env** manualy at the root of your project.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the error in composer version 1. Fortunately, I was able to fix this issue by updating to the latest version of the composer.

```
sudo composer self-update --2
```